# How to read $ character while reading a csv using pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, encoding, special-characters, dollar-sign

I want to ignore the $ sign while reading the csv file . I have used multiple encoding options such as `latin-1`, `utf-8`, `utf-16`, `utf-32`, `ascii`, `utf-8-sig`, `unicode_escape`, `rot_13`

Also `encoding_errors = 'replace'` but nothing seems to work
below is a dummy data set which reads the '$' as below. It converts the text in between '$' to bold-italic font.

[image]

This is how the original data set looks like

[image]

code :

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\nitin2.bhatt\\Downloads\\CCL\\dummy.csv")
df.head()
```

please help as I have referred to multiple blogs but couldn't find a solution to this

Comment: A pandas dataframe does not have a notion of "containing italic text". Whatever makes it italic has to do with formatting/displaying of the dataframe, not the data stored in it. Please use `print(df.head())` or similar to show us more.

Comment: You're running into this issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19824
Keep in mind the distinction between the data in the dataframe and how it is displayed in any particular medium. That is: your csv is already parsed correctly, but displayed incorrectly.